# Read Excel WordArt in Python

Tags: python, excel

Any One tried to read excel WordArt that is inside XLS files.
I'm using the below code but the problem it is dependent on MS Excel Application and needs to open the excel file, and this requires me to interact to input enable/disable Macros.

```
import xlwings as xw  
app = xw.App(visible=False,add_book=False)  
wb = app.books.open('gwk2mus201(32923r1)sample.xls')  
for sheet in wb.sheets:  
    for shape in sheet.shapes:  
        if "WordArt" in shape.name:  
            print(shape.text)            
wb.close()  
app.quit()
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing why you're having to enable/disable macros for an .xls file (i.e. not .xlsm). Can you explain further?

Comment: Actually this automatically happening as the code opens excel application to read the data, and most of the files include Marcos and requires user input to enable\disable them.

Comment: Is there any way to read WordArt in python automatically without user prompt

Comment: As a first step, I'd recommend opening as read-only.